# HTML tags inside json..view using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

Here is my json data

```
[{"Country" : "Germ<sup>any</sup>"},{"Country" : "Swe<sup>den</sup>"}]
```

Here is how i am fetching it using angular js

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="customersController"> 
<ul><li ng-repeat="x in names">{{ x.Country }}</li></ul>
</div>
```

and the controller script

```
function customersController($scope,$http){
$http.get("http://localhost/sample.php").success(function(response) {$scope.names = response;});
}
```

---

The output i am getting is

```html
<ul>
<li>Germ&lt;sup&gt;any&lt;/sup&gt;</li>
<li>Sweden</li>
 </ul>
```

But the output i wanted is

```html
<ul>
<li>Germ<sup>any</sup></li>
<li>Swe<sup>den</sup></li>
</ul>
```

Need help to sort this out...

Comment: You always want the last three letters are `<sup>`'ed?

Comment: Not only sup, i may use any tags like b or strong etc.

Comment: if you run the first code snippet then you can know what the output i am getting and the second is what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ng-bind-html` for the div you are trying to print HTML content.

Refer to [this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) for details and change the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

By default, AngularJS sanitises your data and strips all HTML.

To achieve what you desire, use the [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) service to mark the data as trusted and the [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) directive to bind it to the view, like this:

**Add a new filter**

```
app.filter('unsafe', ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return function(text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };
}])
```

**Use it in HTML**

```
<ANY ng-bind-html="data | unsafe"></ANY>
```